# How to play audio on a PHP/HTML/Javascript based game on facebook?

Tags: javascript, audio

Is there any way how to play audio for the game slot machine when the reels spinning using javascript.

I tried using ,  and tags.. The music is playing but on some of the versions there is no sync..

The process is:
- Once the spin button is pressed.. I am showing the animated reels images and embeding the music file with  tags.

May be is there any better solution to load music file before and play using .play() function in javascript. I tried this but not working on someversions of firefox and other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

One solution some use is multiple instances of jPlayer (one per channel).  You can then preload the sounds and .play() them at will.

jPlayer will try to do HTML5 and use Flash as a backup solution.

http://jplayer.org/